# Get Hardware and System information of computers on the local network via Python

Tags: python

How to get hardware information of a computer on a local network. (IP, MAC, computer name, user, RAM, Mainbroad, Operating System, Processor,...)
I researched the **platform** và **Win32_ComputerSystem** but could only check the current computer's information.
All the computers I want to get data from have the same administrator account.
Can anyone help me about the method and its code?

```
from tkinter import *
import wmi
import platform, socket
import cpuinfo

S = wmi.WMI()
my_system = S.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0]
Ram = str(round(int(my_system.TotalPhysicalMemory) / (1024.0 **3)))+" GB"
Ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
CPUinfo = cpuinfo.get_cpu_info()['brand_raw']
OpSys = platform.platform()
User = my_system.UserName

master = Tk()
master.title('Get info PC')
Label(master, text="\nManufactured: "+ my_system.Manufacturer).grid(row=0,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nModell: "+ my_system.Model).grid(row=1,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nName: "+ my_system.Name).grid(row=2,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nOperator System: "+ OpSys).grid(row=3,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nSystem Type: "+ my_system.SystemType).grid(row=4,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nRAM: "+ Ram).grid(row=5,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nProcessor: "+ CPUinfo).grid(row=6,column=1)
Label(master, text="Ip Address: "+ Ip).grid(row=7,column=1)
Label(master, text="\nUserName: "+ User[User.find('\\')+1:]).grid(row=8,column=1)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get hardware information about another machine without (at some level) logging into that machine.  It either requires you to explicitly set up login accounts on all of the machines, OR install and enable some kind of remote management software on them.  It is not something that can be done in a simple Python script.

If you were asking this in the context of Linux, I would suggest that you look at one of the pre-existing configuration and management frameworks; e.g. Puppet, Chef, Salt, Ansible and so on.  Note that these all (I think) require you to preinstall agent software on each machine that is to be managed.  I am not familiar with the tools commonly used for this in the context of Windows.

The other approach is to simply script something to get (say) an SSH session into the remote machine, run a command on the remote, and capture the output.  But there are all sorts of hidden traps in this ... not least that you *could* open a massive security hole if you do this incorrectly.

I think you are likely to get better answers if you treat this as a systems administration problem rather than a programming problem.  Try searching (and if necessary asking) on ServerFault.

Comment: All the computers I want to get data from have the same administrator account. I want to scan all computers within IP range in lan network. Using SSH is not feasible due to security issues

Comment: OK.  So I think you should be asking (on ServerFault) how to securely run commands remotely on Windows and capture the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command "systeminfo" in cmd to get the IP, MAC, computer name, user, RAM, Mainbroad, Operating System, Processor.. of that machine.
To run this command in python install os by typing this into cmd:

```html
pip install os-sys
```

You can then run the system info command with this code snippet:

```html
import os

commandtoexecute =  "systeminfo"

returned_value = os.system(cmd) 
print('returned value:', returned_value)
```

This will run commandtoexecute in cmd and store it in returned_value. It will then print it.

You will need to have access to the computer remotely or have someone run this python script. If you want to get the data to your computer, I recommend that you establish a socket connection between your computer and the other, and transfer the data

Comment: The question asked is about finding out information on **other computers** on the local network.  Does this answer address that?  (And you say that you are running "ipconfig" when you appear to be running "systeminfo".  Is that a typo?)

Comment: Yes. This is a typo.

Comment: And what about the rest of my comment?

Comment: If he has remote access to the system, you can establish a socket connection, and send the data over to your own computer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want to do it from my personal computer and don't want to remote to each machine to do it. The number of computers I need to check is about 160 pcs